# SQL: extract common string from by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a table with a location and device name.  I want to keep the part of the device name that matches within the group.

```
location_code | device_name      | location
1               Building_1_in      Building_1
1               Building_1_out     Building_1
1               Building_1_gate    Building_1
2               Drive 3 gate2      Drive 3
2               Drive 3 gate1      Drive 3
2               Drive 3 keypad     Drive 3
```

I have location code and device name, but I'm trying to create the `location` column.  I can't use a `SUBSTRING` function since the target strings are of different length, and I can't use a `CHARINDEX` function since there is no consistent delimiter.  Also, there are too many `location_code` to write a `CASE WHEN` function.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is it safe to say that at least the first two words is the group name? and can be delimited by any character? what's the longest device_name?

Comment: No, sometimes it's as many as five words for the location name.  Sometimes spaces separate words, other times it's underscores.

Comment: i suppose more samples

Comment: I think that best solution is to normalize this table

Comment: Modify the logic in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864446/query-to-get-common-words-between-two-strings to get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group these records by location_code then
You can get required result by

**Create a Function**

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.getLocation
(
    @location_code int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result varchar(max)

    declare @device_name1 varchar(max)
            ,@device_name2 varchar(max)
            ,@iterator int


    set @result = ''

    select top 1 @device_name1 = device_name from TableName where location_code = @location_code order by device_name
    select top 1 @device_name2 = device_name from TableName where location_code = @location_code order by device_name desc

    set @iterator = 1
    while(@iterator <= len(@device_name1) and @iterator <= len(@device_name2))
    begin

        if(SUBSTRING(@device_name1, @iterator, 1) = SUBSTRING(@device_name2, @iterator, 1))
        begin
            set @result = @result + SUBSTRING(@device_name1, @iterator, 1)
        end
        else
            break
        set @iterator = @iterator + 1
    end

    return @result

END
GO
```

and use it like

```
select t.location_code, t.device_name, l.location
from TableName t
inner join (select location_code, dbo.getLocation(location_code) as location from TableName group by location_code) l on l.location_code = t.location_code
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea:
You can sort the table ordering by location_code and device name. Then you can extract the common begining part of the first and the last for each location_code.

Comment: Your idea helped me improve my logic